# Get count of distinct users in powershell collection

Tags: powershell

I have some users in a collection that I need a count of.

The collection will contain something like this:

> id ------ user ------ itempath
>
> 3 ------user1------ C:\test
>
> 9 ------user1------ C:\test
>
> 26 -----user2------ C:\test
>
> 102 ----user1------ C:\test

What I want to get from this is to get the count of user1 and user2.

so:

> User1 = 3
> User2 = 1

These are the different programs open by a user so the id probably wont be in sequential order which will mean some users may be in the collection before and after another user.

```
foreach ($computer in $computername){
$netfile = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/LanmanServer"

$netfile.Invoke("Resources") | foreach {
    try{
        $collection += New-Object PsObject -Property @{
        Id = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)
        itemPath = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("Path", ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)
        UserName = $_.GetType().InvokeMember("User", ‘GetProperty’, $null, $_, $null)
        
        }
    }
    catch{
        if ($verbose){write-warning $error[0]}
    }
}
foreach($item in $collection){
    if ($item){
    
    }else{
    
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Is there something you tried or perhaps have code to show? This should be handled by `Group-Object User`

Comment: Ive added the code I am using to create the collection and at the moment I am trying to add each distinct user to another collection by looping through the current collection(Last foreach). I think there is a better way of doing this just by using the current list but I have not used power shell all that much and don't know the first place to start looking

Comment: Actually `Group-Object` did work and gave me the count along with it, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3829407/matt)

> Is there something you tried or perhaps have code to show? This should be handled by Group-Object User

This worked for me and gave me the count too.